# MYSQL: LOAD DATA INFILE ... INTO TABLE...; DATETIME filed becomes 0000:00:00 00:00:00

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I have a text file S_data.txt with four columns and a typical row is like:

```
13  Kate  2.138  8/13/2001 13:24:33 (columns are separated by tab)
```

I want to load the data into a table s_table with four fields: S_id MEDIUMINT, S_name VARCHA(20), S_value DOUBLE, S_dt DATETIME.

```
mysql>LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\temp\\S_data.txt' INTO TABLE s_table 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' SET S_dt = STR_TO_DATE(@S_dt,'%m/%d/%y %H:%i:%s');
```

The values of S_dt all become 0000-00-00 00:00:00.

Can someone help? Thanks.

Comment: is the space in the middle of `'%m/%d/%y %H:%i:%s'` also a tab?

Comment: You never set your `@S_dt` variable.

Comment: No. That is just a space. How do I set @S_dt? that may be the problem.

Comment: Then check if it should be changed... Also, why is there a dot after @S_dt, shouldn't it be a comma?

Comment: I actually have a comma in my SQL but made a typo in the post of the question.

Comment: I think you need to list all the columns explicitly to be able to set one of them from a variable, something like `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\temp\\S_data.txt' INTO TABLE s_table 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' (S_id, S_name, S_Value, @S_dt) SET S_dt = STR_TO_DATE(@S_dt,'%m/%d/%y %H:%i:%s');`  Not certain about this syntax though... In any case, the variable `@S_dt` gets set in the column list...

Comment: I also tried: mysql>LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\temp\\S_data.txt' INTO TABLE s_table 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' (S_id, S_name, S_value, @S_dt) SET S_dt = STR_TO_DATE(@S_dt,'%m/%d/%y %H:%i:%s'); but the results are the same.

Comment: please sort out the syntax problem by for instance trying `SET S_Value = CONCAT(@S_Value, '.')`. Doing so, you will ensure your syntax is valid and will then be able to focus on the STR_TO_DATE problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. For my datetime string (e.g. 8/13/2001 13:23:56), I have to use format '%c/%d/%Y %H:%i%S'. Thanks everyone.